# WPF ListView VerticalScrollBar is not shown

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I'm displaying a collection of items on a ListView. The collection is long enough to show the VerticalScrollBar of the ListView but it doesn't work.

My XAML:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyProperty}" Header="MyProperty" />
                        ...
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My UserControl is used like this:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            ...
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" >
            <TabItem Header="myUserControl">
                <views:MyUserControl />
            </TabItem>
            ...
        </TabControl>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Question is where you use your `UserControl`. Currently your `UserControl` will adjust height to `ListView` which will grow, to accommodate all items, if you give it spece

Comment: I'v updated my question and added where and how my user control is used.

Comment: I've followed your example and my `ListView` shows vertical scroll bar just as it should. Are you sure that your `Window` does not have something like `SizeToContent` set? Does the `ListView` display all items or some are missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.
The height of the `Grid` `Row` modified from `"Auto"` to `"*"`.

```
<!-- Row where the ListView is shown -->
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```